# Convert file with int value in each line to IEnumerable<int>

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I have a file with int values in each line (although it's possible that some values are not ints like some comments). But the structure of the file is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
#some comment
9
10
etc...
```

What's the fastest way to convert it to IEnumerable. I could read line by line and use List and call Add method, but I guess it's not the best in terms of performance.

Thanks

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1271236/1180426) might be of use to you if you want truly 'streaming' behavior of the IEnumerable, not a buffered version. :)

Comment: Do you want to get only the lines that are ints?

Comment: "but I guess it's not the best in terms of performance" Don't guess. Try and measure!

Comment: Yes, only lines that are ints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create your `IEnumerable` on-the-fly while reading the file:

```
IEnumerable<Int32> GetInts(string filename)
{
    int tmp = 0;
    foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(filename))
        if (Int32.TryParse(line, out tmp))
            yield return tmp;
}
```

This way, you can do whatever you want to do with your integers while reading the file, using a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach(int i in GetInts(@"yourfile"))
{
    ... do something with i ...
}
```

---

If you just want to create a list, simply use the `ToList` extension:

```
List<Int32> myInts = GetInts(@"yourfile").ToList();
```

but there probably won't be any measurable performance difference if you "manually" create a list as you described in your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(path).Where(l => !l.StartsWith("#"));
```

you can also append `.Select(x => int.Parse(x))`

Comment: I'd suggest `File.ReadLines` instead of `File.ReadAllLines`, for lazy loading.

Comment: are you sure this is faster than using a loop?

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso you are doing Disk IO and sequential read, How much improvement do you expect?

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso but it is using a loop. It's likely to be slightly slower, but so slightly that it gets lost compared to the IO. While I went to the loop approach, I certainly wouldn't argue one over the other on performance, as long as it works sequentially, which it does.

Comment: @L.B I was not talking about the Disk IO which it is not possible to gain in performance but I was talking about using LINQ inestead of a while/for which is always faster than LINQ.
In the past I has a similar problem but the file was contain million of int.I could not improve the IO access but using a classic for was lots more faster than LINQ

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso Linq only brings an overhead of a few more function call, which is nothing when compared to Disk IO. I don't know what you did in the past, but I think you can  easily test it.(You can even ask it here on SO)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IEnumerable<int> ReadInts(TextReader tr)
{
  //put using here to have this manage cleanup, but in calling method
  //is probably better
  for(string line = tr.ReadLine(); line != null; line = tr.ReadLine())
    if(line.Length != 0 && line[0] != '#')
      yield return int.Parse(line);
}
```

I assume from your description that a line that doesn't match **should** throw an exception, but I guessed also that blank lines where you don't want them are very common, so I do cathc that case. Adapt to catch that as appropriate otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add lines only if they are convertible to ints, you could use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). I suggest to use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) instead of [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx)(creates an array in memory):

```
int value;
IEnumerable<String>lines = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Where(l => int.TryParse(l.Trim(), out value));
```

or (if you want to select those ints):

```
int value;
IEnumerable<int>ints= File.ReadLines(path)
    .Where(l => int.TryParse(l.Trim(), out value))
    .Select(l => value);
```