# Reading Byte[] into Database from API

Tags: c#, linq, api, arrays, evernote

I have been reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271225/c-sharp-reading-a-file-line-by-line) as I would like to do this via LINQ. However, I have been unable to figure out how to read the data from the API.

When I output `resource.Data.Body` it says, `Byte[]`.

When I output `resource.Data.Size` it says, `834234822`. (or something like that)

I am trying to save the contents into my database like this:

```
newContent.ATTACHMENT = resource.Data.Body;
```

However, no data is ever loaded. I assume I have to loop through `Body` and store the contents in a variable, but I am not sure how.

Can someone help me connect the dots here?

**Edit:**

This is the source of the binary data I am trying to read http://dev.evernote.com/start/core/resources.php

**Edit 2:**

I am using the following code which gives me binary data and saves to database, but it must be corrupt, or something because when I go to open the file Windows photo viewer says it's corrupt or too large...

```
Resource resource = noteStore.getResource(authToken, attachment.Guid, true, false, true, true);

            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

            foreach(byte b in resource.Data.Body)
            {
                data.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));  
            }
...
newContent.ATTACHMENT = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data.ToString());
```

Comment: What exactly is `newContent` and it's associated property `ATTACHMENT`?

Comment: It is an object via LINQ (mirrors my database) `ATTACHMENTS_CONTENT newContent = new ATTACHMENTS_CONTENT();`

Comment: And the property `ATTACHMENT`, is that a `byte[]`?

Comment: It is an `image` type (in the database).  **Edit:** In the .cs file from LINQ, it is `public System.Data.Linq.Binary ATTACHMENT`

Comment: Here is the resource structure if it helps http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/Types.html#Struct_Resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `resource.Data.Body` is `byte[]`, and `newContent.ATTACHMENT` is `System.Data.Linq.Binary`, you should use the constructor on `System.Data.Linq.Binary` which takes an input parameter of type `byte[]`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351422.aspx

```
newContent.ATTACHMENT = new System.Data.Linq.Binary(resource.Data.Body);
```

Comment: I have gotten a little further, please see my update and let me know your opinion.  It appears the file binary data is corrupt, so I assume I'm not retrieving it in the proper way.

Comment: Maybe I have the wrong encoding?  I am not sure how to check.

Comment: Why are you now converting `data` to string and then back to ASCII encoded bytes? That operation will *always* corrupt binary data.

Comment: If I just do `newContent.ATTACHMENT = data;` it says, "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Text.StringBuilder' to 'System.Data.Linq.Binary'"

Comment: AH HA!  I just tried you solution and it worked!  Thanks so much.