# How to read each line of file in loop?

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I have a `System.IO.Stream` that I'm getting content from (a file).  I do the following:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(mystream))
{
  var filecontent = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

That only captures a single line. I'd like to put each line into a `List<String>`. How can that be done?

Comment: Why not use [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx)? (since you say you're getting the content from a file)

Comment: Where do you get File from? I only have a Stream.

Comment: ReadAllLines is appropriate for small files, but loads everything into memory. This is a good idea in this specific case that the OP wants a `List<string>`, but future readers be aware that it's not always the best way to "read each line of file in loop".

Comment: @4thSpace: System.IO.File.ReadAllLines https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Linked as duplicate post shows multiple ways to read files/streams (or use iterator shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271225/c-sharp-reading-a-file-line-by-line)... But I'd recommend reading on some C# basics first like loops (`while`/`for`) as it seem to be main problem in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inside the `using` add

```
while (reader.Peek() >= 0){
   list.add(reader.readline);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a file :

```
 List<string> allLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList();
```

In case of you have steam instead of a file :

```
List<string> allLines = new List<string>();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
        allLines.Add(line); // Add to list.     
        }
    }
```